# Make * stay on current keyword

Tags: search

I often use `*` with `cgn` and end up missing the first match (or doing `*N...`). So I'd prefer for `*` to stay where it is.

```
nnoremap * *N
```

Does almost what I want except it recenters the cursor line. Is there a better way?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can do that with this mapping:

```
nnoremap <silent> * :let @/=expand("<cword>")<CR>
```

That sets the search register, `@/`, to the word under the cursor, `<cword>`. See also

```
:help quote/
:help <cword>
```

Comment: interestingly, this technique also searches for the text of `<cword>` inside other words.  e.g.  hitting `*` on "word" highlights it inside "cword" as well.

Comment: ok, then I edited and tested (silly me) and this way works for matching single words... `nnoremap <silent> * :let @/="\\<".expand("<cword>")."\\>"<CR>`